# Size of apk on different codebase

Tags: java, android, flutter, react-native, kotlin

how using #Kotlin, #ReactNative or #Flutter can affect your Android app size? (tldr; Java-1MB, Kotlin 1.5MB, React Native 7MB, Flutter 7.5MB)

Is there any way to make React Native of smaller size?

Tried this:

```
 Open up android/app/build.gradle
Set def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true this would enable Progaurd to compress the Java Bytecode. This reduces the app size by a tad bit
Set def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true . Android devices support two major device artitectures armebi and x86. By default RN builds the native librariers for both these artitectures into the same apk.
```